# Omit seems broken on type extending Record

Tags: typescript

Something unexpected happen when I use Omit to get rid of the member of source interface for extension.

If I extend `A` without omit, both `a1` and `a2` props are required. But I want to have `a2` not present in `B` but inherit all other members from type `A`.

When I use Omit, somehow even a1 become optional, but I expect to `a1` stay required.

```
interface A extends Record<string, any> {
    a1: string;
    a2: number;
}

interface B extends Omit<A, 'a2'>{
    b1: string;
    b2: number;
}

const example: B = {
    // a1: 'dfdf', // should throw error, a1 is required
    b1: 'string',
    b2: 12,
}
```

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIgD0iAJgZ2QCUIEB7KXAHnzClAHMAaZOEATwD5kBvAKGSDWARgBcyWvRAMA3AKFwATOJABXALYAjaHIC%20fPqEixEKAEIZsEPIQDy64GCqoWAciWvO-Ick1iJdIxyPprKyGpaOnz6fOQgtJZw6gAOADYQ4hYAvLzyggD0%20SLirrgwZa5Meb7%20rpKMldWh4sKKVbpAA)

Thanks for any hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to implement your own version of [the `Omit<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) that respects [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#49656](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49656):

```
type Oops = Omit<A, "a2">;
/* type Oops = {
    [x: string]: any;
    [x: number]: any;
} // ☹ */

type MyOmit<T, K extends PropertyKey> =
    { [P in keyof T as Exclude<P, K>]: T[P] }

type Okay = MyOmit<A, "a2">;
/* type Okay = {
    [x: string]: any;
    a1: string;
} //  */
```

The `Omit<T, K>` utility type was introduced before key remapping was available.
There is an issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#41383](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41383) suggesting that key remapping be used instead, but it's unlikely to happen in production (see [this comment on ms/TS#49656](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49656#issuecomment-1164655820)).

Generally speaking once a utility type is introduced, it's not easy to redefine it without breaking real world code.  Indeed there are several "problems" with `Omit` that can't be addressed; index signatures is one issue, and distributing over unions is another (e.g., people expect `Omit<T | U, K>` to be equivalent to `Omit<T, K> | Omit<U, K>`, but it isn't).  See [microsoft/TypeScript#53169](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53169) for discussion of a potential fix for union distribution, along with all the problems that arise when trying to use it.  All this means: if a TypeScript-provided utility type doesn't behave as you think it should, you should write your own utility type that does.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDyBbAlsAPAFQDRQNJQgA9gIA7AEwGcoAFAJwHtI7RcIQA+KAXgCgoBUAN5QA2jSjJSUANbsGAMygYoAQ2oBRQgGMANgFdyENDRy4OAXQBcy8RagBfXrykk6C1dugBBAsTJUUABKENoMdORolMB0UgDmOKqknML8gqoAjDbRsaRxANxpAqoATDak+ogARhB0hU68oJBQ8EzU3C0o6N44AESlvRyFAPQAVFBN0K1g7amCYoTZMfHWasmF86KLUBXVtatJIPVQo8POky0yqiA8sAhdaD1Q-SWDI+MX8Fc3HUJFC0tcnEDut-plAfFjqdnK5ah4vFAAEJ+EgUahwJCoR44ADkpRxXD+8yqWSgOUh-yqZR2lRqdV4DTCpGiflUiDAuggNmRv3+w2GalJOPIChFOKwlKF5Ly4sp1IyJQlDiAA)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can not `Omit` on `Record<string, any>` the reason being that `Omit` relies on `keyof` which when used on an index with `string` results in `string`. i.e.

doing `string | "a"` will always result in `string` as that type is considered wider than "a" and thus ends up swallowing the other types.

Details provided in the following [50638](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50638).

There is a work around given in the link (credit to augustobmoura):

```
// Returns a type with the same well-known props, but without the index signature
type NoIndex<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as {} extends Record<K, 1> ? never : K]: T[K]
}

// Inverse of NoIndex, meaning it only gets the index signature of a type, ignoring other well known props
type OnlyIndex<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as {} extends Record<K, 1> ? K : never]: T[K]
}

// Omit from NoIndex version of T, and then intersects with the indexed part of it
type OmitFromKnownKeys<T, K extends keyof NoIndex<T>> = Omit<NoIndex<T>, K> & OnlyIndex<T>

interface A extends Record<string, any> {
    a1: string;
    a2: number;
}

interface B extends OmitFromKnownKeys<A, 'a2'>{
    b1: string;
    b2: number;
}

const example: B = { // now throws error, a1 is required
    // a1: 'dfdf', 
    b1: 'string',
    b2: 12,
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply an explanation  I like the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76616671/861615) more as it is simpler.. but it can be learned a lot also from your solution, thanks